# Redis Timeseries - Representing the numberic value as a list of values

Tags: redis, redistimeseries

I'm new to Redis Timeseries and I'd like to know if it is possible to add data to a TS as **a list of values** instead of a single numeric value.

Here my specific example about representing **trading candles**:

```
# Creating a TS for open and close values
TS.CREATE BTCUSD1H_OPEN
TS.CREATE BTCUSD1H_CLOSE
# adding values for each one of them at the same timestamp
TS.ADD BTCUSD1H_OPEN 1652824475581 21.000
TS.ADD BTCUSD1H_CLOSE 1652824475581 20.000
```

Everything is correct and working fine, but I'm asking myself:
**is there a way in Redis to use a single TS with a list of values for each timestamp?**

In the above example it would be something like:

```
# Just ONE timeseries, for BOTH open and close values
TS.CREATE BTCUSD1H
# adding values as list (first one is "open", second one is "close")
TS.ADD BTCUSD1H 1652824475581 21.000, 20.000
```

Of course, this last example doesn't work because it violates the Redis syntax.

From the documentation it seems to be not possible, but I'm asking here maybe there is a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. RedisTimeSeries is currently (v1.X) a single-column time series database, which means that a time series is a set of (timestamp, value) pairs. You are asking about multi-column (or multi-metric) capability.

Nevertheless, by creating multiple time series you are not loosing any capabilities. You gain simplicity and also better flexibility for handling missing values. Due to the [efficient compression](https://redis.com/blog/redistimeseries-version-1-2-is-here/), the extra memory required is minimal, and using labels as secondary indexes you can easily query data from multiple time series.